# Uploading a file from a local .net application through the HTML Form file upload feature (php server side)

Tags: c#, php, file-upload

I want to make a local program in C# that manages files between multiple users. I want to utilize the file upload option supported by HTML Form/PHP from within a .net application, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Even a starting point would be awesome.

All my google searches return using the HTML Form upload from within a web browser, but I'm looking to use the same upload feature directly from a local .net application.

Thanks

Kurru

Comment: I have no idea about C# so I can't pick the best one, but there are several dupes, one of which should help: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C%23+remote+file+upload

Answer (score 0):

The [UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile.aspx) function is a good starting point:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] result = client.UploadFile(
        "http://foo.com/upload.php", 
        @"c:\work\foo.txt"
    );
}
```